# Why do I get goaway from Bigtable in my C++ application?

Tags: c++, grpc, google-cloud-bigtable

I am running a data import job written in C++ using gRPC Bigtable client. After a period of time and over 1M records inserted I am getting `goaway` with `max_age` message. This is my first in general and first long running Bigtable application, so I am not sure if that `goaway` is specific to the number of inserts being made or to the connection duration, or what that `goaway` really is. It seems that I am hitting a timeout of some kind. Looking at the gRPC C++ code, grpc::Channel specifically, I do not see any timeout controls, so I am not sure how to deal with that problem, except for re-opening DB connection anew.

The exact error message that I am getting from gRPC client looks like this:

```
D0127 23:05:35.439218531   19729 chttp2_transport.c:683]     got goaway [0]: 6d 61 78 5f 61 67 65 'max_age'
```

gRPC and protobuf are built from source, from the mainline around 01/22/16, so the client code is recent.

Any suggestions as to why Bigtable would send `goaway`? And is it possible to open a `grpc::Channel` that does not timeout when talking to Bigtable?

Comment: Just a guess - but if it was about an hour after you started, you might wish to refresh the auth token.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with the java side, so I hope this helps.  There is a 1 hour timeout on a connection for connections with constant use.  The java channel also times out after a short time without any activity (on the order of minutes).

Answer (score 0):

What client are you using? Currently the gRPC C++ implementation will shutdown the channel once a goaway is received. This is a bit too aggressive and you may want to check the channel state and recreate the channel if you see it's in FATAL_FAILURE.

What Solomon said is right about the timeout.